# speeden up Haar Cascade training process

Tags: gpu, haar-classifier

Training a haar cascade takes a lot of time and also the entire training period depends on the machine.
What are the **factors** that contribute to speeding up the process?
Does having more RAM and a GPU help?
Does haar cascade training have GPU support like tensorflow does?

Answer (score 0):

Opencv documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html) state that

> LBP features yield integer precision in contrast to HAAR features, yielding floating point precision, so both training and detection with LBP are several times faster then with HAAR features. Regarding the LBP and HAAR detection quality, it mainly depends on the training data used and the training parameters selected. It's possible to train a LBP-based classifier that will provide almost the same quality as HAAR-based one, within a percentage of the training time.

So while training, instead of using old opencv_haartraining tool use opencv_traincascade tool with -featureType LBP as a parameter(default is HAAR)

Also, you can use -precalcValBufSize and -precalcIdxBufSize parameters to assign specific amount of memory for training. The more memory you assign the faster the training process, however keep in mind that -precalcValBufSize and -precalcIdxBufSize combined should not exceed your available system memory.